# Onclick html attribute not Working in Windows 10 UWP apps

Tags: javascript, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1, windows-10

First microsoft removed support for href:javascript:function() and only onclick=function() was allowed. Now even onclick is not working in UWP apps or am i doing something wrong. None of the samples from github are using onclick and they are using addeventlistener in javascript. So is it not supported? The the documentation says it is supported.

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem. What about IntelliSense it supports click attribute. And by clicking F12 I can go to definition.
Have replaced click attribute with JS code like:

```
document.getElementById('btnSelectFolder').addEventListener("click", stgm);
```